# Javascrip static class

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently developing a class that only contains static fields and methods as it doesn't need to hold any state (it is just a class that parses a message and runs the command contained in it).

When I require the class and console.log it, I get all of the properties that it should have, but when I call them one by one, all of them appear undefined:

The output when I log the class:

```
const Executor = require('./executor.js')
console.log(Executor.COMMANDS)
```

```
OUTPUT:
{
    Executor: [class Executor] {
      COMMANDS: {
        none: -1,
        follow: 1,
        dig_area: 2,
        silent_mode: 3,
        help: 4,
        tp: 5
      },
      run: [Function: run]
    }
}
```

And here is the actual class as it is:

```
class Executor
{
    /*
    All fields and methods are static as they shouldn't hold any state variable
    given that all commands must run independently
    */
    
    static COMMANDS = {

        none: -1,
        follow: 1,
        dig_area: 2,
        silent_mode: 3,
        help: 4,
        tp: 5

    };
    
    
    

    static run = (message, username) => {
        
        const { command, body } = Parser.parse(message);
        console.log(`Command: ${command}\t Body: ${body}`)
        
        switch(command)
        {
            case COMMANDS.follow:
                break;
            
            case COMMANDS.dig_area:
                break;

            case COMMANDS.silent_mode:
                break;

            case COMMANDS.help:
                break;

            case COMMANDS.tp:
                break;

            case COMMANDS.none:
                break;

        }
    } 
}



class Parser
{
    //Prefix which will preceed any command given to the boy
    static PREFIX = '!';

    //List of command values to pass to the Command Executor

    static COMMANDS = {

        
        'follow': Executor.COMMANDS.follow,
        'dig_area': Executor.COMMANDS.dig_area,
        'silent_mode': Executor.COMMANDS.silent_mode,
        'help': Executor.COMMANDS.help,
        'tp': Executor.COMMANDS.tp
        
    }

    
    //Should return the whole message array but the last aparison
    static parse(message, username)
    {
        StringArr = message.split(' ');
        isCommand =  StringArr.shift() === this.PREFIX;
        
        if(!isCommand) return -1
        
        return { command: COMMANDS[StringArr[0]], body: StringArr};
    }

}


module.exports.Executor = Executor;
```

I don't know why it loads the class correctly but it gets undefined any time I access any of the properties, either function or field. Also, when defining run as an usual function like this, it didn't detect it as a property of the class:

```
class Executor
{
    /*
    All fields and methods are static as they shouldn't hold any state variable
    given that all commands must run independently
    */

    static COMMANDS = {

        none: -1,
        follow: 1,
        dig_area: 2,
        silent_mode: 3,
        help: 4,
        tp: 5

    };




    static run(message, username){

        const { command, body } = Parser.parse(message);
        console.log(`Command: ${command}\t Body: ${body}`)

        switch(command)
        {
            case COMMANDS.follow:
                break;

            case COMMANDS.dig_area:
                break;

            case COMMANDS.silent_mode:
                break;

            case COMMANDS.help:
                break;

            case COMMANDS.tp:
                break;

            case COMMANDS.none:
                break;

        }
    }
```

Any help would be kindly appreciated. Thank you all!

Comment: Side-note: "static class" signifies where OO fails to model things. Languages like C# and Java are less flexible and do not even have another way to represent stateless operations or data. With JS you can simply have a module that exports a function (stateless operation) and data which more correctly matches what you have. Consider using those instead of a broken OO model for these situations.

Comment: Please read the first console output again more carefully. It doesn't output the class, it outputs _an object with a property `Executor` set to the class_. So the way you imported it, you'd have to write `Executor.Executor` to get the actuall class. It's because you did `module.exports.Executor = Executor` instead of `module.exports = Executor` in your module. However, that works too, if you import it like this: `const { Executor } = require('./executor.js')`.

Comment: @VLAZ Well, I thought the same in the past, until I ran into the situation (several times!) that I suddenly had to create variations and extensions of that functionality, and it became very useful to use `extends` and `super` with some static methods of the class.

Comment: @CherryDT I am a bit lost about all this and would like to review this stuff. Do you know ay good resource where I can go through OOP again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need a "static class"?

What you're talking about is simply a module that exports an object with properties:

```
const COMMANDS = {
  follow      :  1 ,
  dig_area    :  2 ,
  silent_mode :  3 ,
  help        :  4 , 
  tp          :  5
}

const Parser = {

  //Prefix which will preceed any command given to the boy
  PREFIX: '!',

  //List of command values to pass to the Command Executor
  COMMANDS: {...COMMANDS},

  //Should return the whole message array but the last aparison
  parse(message, username) {
    const [ pfx , cmd, ...body ] = message.split(' ');
    const isCommand = pfx === this.PREFIX;
    return isCommand ? { command: this.COMMANDS[cmd], body } : -1;
  }

}

const Executor = {

  COMMANDS: { none: -1, ...COMMANDS},

  run: (message, username) => {
    const { command, body } = Parser.parse(message);

    console.log(`Command: ${command}\t Body: ${body}`)

    switch (command) {
      case this.COMMANDS.follow:      break;
      case this.COMMANDS.dig_area:    break;
      case this.COMMANDS.silent_mode: break;
      case this.COMMANDS.help:        break;
      case this.COMMANDS.tp:          break;
      case this.COMMANDS.none:        break;
    }

  }

};
exports = modules.exports = Executor;
```

If you ensure that it's immutable, then `Object.freeze()` it:

```
const Executor = Object.freeze({

  COMMANDS: Object.freeze({ none: -1, ...COMMANDS}),

  run: (message, username) => {
    . . .
  },

});
```

Comment: As a JS noob question, defining Parser, Executor, etc. like that, should I instantiate them as if they were a class with the new operator? I am a little bit lost with all this prototype inheritance, so if you know any good resource I'd appreciate it a lot.